# Eval scripts in server side control property

Tags: asp.net, controls, eval

how do i implement an eval script in a sever side control?

eg. `<a runat="server" href="?id=<%= Eval("Id") %>">hello world</a>`

Answer (score 2):

If the server-side control is within a databound control (ListView, GridView, FormView, DetailsView), then the syntax is: `<%# Eval("Id") %>`.

If the server-side control is not within a databound control, you will have to access it via the code-behind and set your attribute there.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, its <%# instead of <%=

Answer (score 1):

The Data-Binding expression is your friend, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) for examples.